# Why is it possible to merge two const enums in typescript?

Tags: typescript, enums, constants

Const by definition means that a particular value should be constant. It should not be possible to modify, redeclare or reassign it. Yet when an enum is declared as const, it is possible to declare another const enum of the same name and it will be merged (even if two keys have the same value).

```
    const enum Color {
        Red,
        Green,
        Blue
    }
    
// Some lines of Code
// and then at the end of the file

    const enum Color {
        DarkRed = 0,
        DarkGreen,
        DarkBlue
    }
    
    const i = Color.Red; // gives 0
    const j = Color.DarkRed; // gives 0
```

Although if the second enum declaration is not const, it will throw an error (which is logical as Const enum members are inlined at use sites).

Comment: Use regular immutable objects instead of enums

Comment: @captain-yossarian: you mean like this - https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#objects-vs-enums, right ?

Comment: Yes, exactly....

Comment: I don't know if there's an authoritative answer to this question. `const enum`s were implemented in [ms/TS#970](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/970) and [released in TS1.4](//www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-4.html#const-enum-completely-inlined-enums).  I see no obvious link to a design discussion that would be a source for an answer. Note that the name `const` in `const enum` does not necessarily imply the sort of `const`-ness you're talking about; generally the TS team likes to introduce new keywords sparingly, so you shouldn't read too much into it.

Comment: `const enum` doesn't mean it cannot be modified, redeclared or reassigned. I just means that members will be inlined, merging is not forbidden. In javascript `const` in general doesn't really imply much of a constness, like you can still assign properties to `const` variables and stuff like that